# iOS location of PHAsset: accuracy is always 0

Tags: ios, location, photokit

I'm trying to extract location information from the user's Photo library using PhotoKit. Trouble is, all CLLocation objects have a horizontalAccuracy of 0...

Wether it is PHAssetCollection.approximateLocation.horizontalAccuracy or PHAsset.location.horizontalAccuracy doesn't make a difference.

This information is important in my use case, and I know for a fact that in certain circumstances accuracy can be absolutely dreadful( error radius of more than 500 metres ).

Any insights appreciated!

Comment: Can you comment with some more details?  What all is in the CLLocation object? How are your retrieving it?

Comment: I am seeing the same thing.  I fetch all PHAssets, and get the CLLocation object by using PHAsset.location.  The horizontalAccuracy of CLLocation object is 0 for most of my assets.  Out of 3000 photos, only 5-10 of them have a value greater than 0 for horizontalAccuracy, but all of them have valid GPS coordinates.